How to properly type a mongoDB filter argument with operators?
I have the following function in my database layer:
public async findByFilter(filter: Partial<InterfaceMongooseModel>): Promise<InterfaceMongooseModel> {
    return MongooseModel.findOne(filter);
}

This works for most cases. However, if I have the following filter:
{
  property: value,
  createdDate: { $gte: oneDayAgo },
}

I will have a type error.
The best solution I found so far is this:
public async findByFilter(filter: object): Promise<InterfaceMongooseModel> {
    return MongooseModel.findOne(filter);
}

However, this is too generic and doesn't provide much information. I wander if there's anything more specific to use in this case.
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I would like to have a proper type for the argument in a mongoDB query.

did u find a type called FilterQuery

Thank you, that's it. You wanna make an answer? or should I delete this question altogether?

idk i can make one. or you can answer youself

Mongoose has the FilterQuery type for filter queries. This is the proper usage in this case:
public async findByFilter(filter: FilterQuery<InterfaceMongooseModel>): Promise<InterfaceMongooseModel> {
    return MongooseModel.findOne(filter);
}

Thanks @cmgchess for pointing this out.

The mongodb store the date with format
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ
and i think you are passing the date with wrong format to apply filters.
pass the date with correct format
